# Regex to replace two consecutive dots with Null

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am trying to replace two dots following each other with Null.

```
SQL> select regexp_replace('..','[^\.]+\.','Null') from dual;
```

produces:

```
RE
--
..
```

whereas I want:

```
RE
--
Null
```

How do I achieve this using Regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT regexp_replace( '..', '\.{2}', 'Null' ) FROM dual;
```

Your example is using the `^` symbol for negation ("do not match a `.`"), which I'm not sure is your intention.  If you are instead wanting to match `..` only at the beginning of a string, use `^` as follows:

```
SELECT regexp_replace( '..', '^\.{2}', 'Null' ) FROM dual;
```

Comment: Brilliant not sure why mine didnt work and strange neither this works select regexp_replace('..','[^\.]{2}','Null') from dual;

Comment: @jhon.smith: ^ has two distinct uses in Regex: 1) for negation inside a character set (which is how you're using it) and 2) to match the beginning of a string.  [^\.]{2} instructs Regex to "match two consecutive NON-DOT characters", whereas ^[\.]{2} says "match two dots at the beginning of a string".

Comment: Thanks brilliant explanation as well why mine did not work :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is going to look a little hairy but for the regex parameter:

```
(?!\.{3,})\.{2}(?<!\.{3,})
```

That will make sure there's not any more or any less than 2 .. following each other, from either the front or the back.

So it'll only match .., not ..., not ., etc.  I'm assuming this is what you want.

Comment: Heck Jason yes you hacked my mind no computer on the universe can read my mind and give me an answer

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for two dots at the beginning of a line, perhaps the simplest expression which could possibly work is

`SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('..', '^\.\.', 'Null') FROM DUAL`

If you're looking for two dots anywhere in the line remove the `^` at the beginning of the expression.

If you're looking for two dots which comprise the entire line, add `$` at the end of the expression, as in

`'^\.\.$'`

Documentation for regular expression elements supported by Oracle can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/ap_posix.htm).

Share and enjoy.